# R How to visualize pairwise alignment

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, sequence-alignment

How to visualize the complete alignment of two sequences?

```
library(Biostrings)
s1 <-DNAString("ACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATCAAAGGAAACGCAAAGTTTTCACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATCAAAGGAAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAGAAGACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATCAAAGGAAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAG")
s2 <-DNAString("GTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAATATATGTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTGTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAATATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATCAAATATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATCAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATC")
pairwiseAlignment(s1,s2)
```

Output:

```
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [1] ACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATCAAAGGAAACGCAAAGT--TTTCAC---...CTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTG-ATCAAAGG---AAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAG 
subject: [1] GTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAAT-ATATGTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTA...TATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATCAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATC 
score: -394.7115
```

Here, only a part of alignment has been shown? Do you know of any existing functions that either plot or print the alignment?

Answer (score 11):

You can find information and details on how to extract the aligned pattern and subject sequences under `?pairwiseAlignments`.

Here is an example based on the sample data you provide:

1. Store the pairwise alignment in a `PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject` object

   ```
   alg <- pairwiseAlignment(s1,s2)
   ```
2. Extract the aligned pattern and subject sequences and merge them into a `DNAStringSet` object.

   ```
   seq <- c(alignedPattern(alg), alignedSubject(alg))
   ```
3. You can access the full sequences with `as.character`

   ```
   as.character(seq)
   [1] "ACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATCAAAGGAAACGCAAAGT--TTTCAC--------TTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATC---AAAGG---AAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAGAAGACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTG-ATCAAAGG---AAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAG"
   [2] "GTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAAT-ATATGTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTGTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAATATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATCAA-ATATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATCAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATC"
   ```

   It seems that `alignedPattern` and `alignedSubject` were added to `Biostrings` very recently. Alternatively you can do

   ```
   seq <- c(aligned(pattern(alg)), aligned(subject(alg)))
   ```

   but note that this will trim globally aligned sequences (see [details](https://github.com/Bioconductor/Biostrings/commit/750f92a0fcaef5fa998876db628ac3ca091806d9)).
4. There exists a nice R/Bioconductor package `DECIPHER` which offers a method to visualise `XStringSet` data in a web browser. It automatically adds colour-coding and a consensus sequence at the bottom. In your case, you would do

   ```
   library(DECIPHER)
   BrowseSeqs(seq)
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Functions alignedPattern, alignedSubject are not available.

Comment: @Prradep They are part of `Biostrings`. Are you having reasonably current R/BIoconductor versions? I'm using R 3.4.0 with `Biostrings_2.48.0`.

Comment: Thanks, I have R version 3.4.4;  ‘Biostrings’ version 2.46.0. I will update them and check! BTW, do you know any possibility to find stop codons in the alignment?

Comment: @Prradep It seems `alignedPattern` and `alignedSubject` were added fairly recently; I've made an edit to show an alternative. Concerning your second question, SO guidelines suggest you should close this question first by setting the green check mark next to the answer. Then open a new question.

Comment: I finally managed to get the system running for `DECIPHER` package.  `BrowseSeqs` function works perfectly fine but only generates an external html file. I would like this to force to an image. Does this package have any functions for that?